# Fixing a catastrophic backtracking in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm on Python and would like to use the `(\n\s*)+(\n//)` regular expression (with `re.sub`).

I fall into catastrophic backtracking. OK, but still, that's the regex I need.

If there is another way to write it which runs in a reasonable time, I don't find it.

Or should I use [re2](https://pypi.org/project/re2/)?

Comment: Try `\n[\n\s]*(\n//)`. It should be the same.

Comment: Your regex can't match if there is more than one space in a row (and mine can)

Comment: What do you mean? See https://regex101.com/r/PULjQe/1

Comment: In your link only the end of the string matches the regex but the whole should (see https://regex101.com/r/qA4bzQ/1)

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two variants except that mine only has one group but I assume you don't need the content of your first group. Both expressions match the whole string.

Comment: Remove the plus sign from the capture group `(\n\s*)(\n//)` https://regex101.com/r/puDFss/1

Comment: does `(\s*)(\n//)` work?

Comment: @Michael: my bad you're right

Comment: @Bird: well the meaninng would not be the same

Comment: @d.b: no, there can be more than one newline character

Comment: I think the problem is just due to `\s*` - you wanted to match non-`\n`s only, so `(?:\n[^\S\n]*)+\n//` should work.

Comment: @Zlotz "*the meaninng would not be the same*": `(\n\s*)+` is the same as `\n\s*`, since `\s` is a superset of `\n`. See also Wiktor's comment right above. To be even safer you can throw in a possessive quantifier (3.11+) *and* the end-of-line anchor: `(\n[^\S\n]*$)++`.

Comment: @Zlotz Can you update your question with some example data, what should and should not match? Do you want 2 capture groups?

Answer (score -1):

As given by Michael Butscher, `\n[\n\s]*(\n//)` is an equivalent regex which runs in a reasonable time.

But `\n\s*(\n//)` given by InSync is simpler because `\s` covers the newline character.

Comment: ...which means the same as `\n\s*(\n//)`.

Comment: Incorrect. `\s` is a superset of `\n` and will also match newlines. The union `[\n\s]`, therefore, is the same as just `\s`.